# Is it possible to perform partition addition every hour while flink job write data to hdfs file?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Currently, Flink can write data directly to hdfs file in ORC format for hive but need to insert partition every hour to the HIVE table. Is there any way to trigger a function every hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can have a `KeyedProcessFunction` with a timer that fires every hour. Or you can write a custom sink that implements `ProcessingTimeCallback` (or maybe extend the sink you're using for HIVE to do this?). You could also implement a custom source that emits an event once an hour.

[ProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#process-function)

[ProcessingTimeCallback](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/tasks/ProcessingTimeCallback.html)

Comment: the code will be running in all task managers right? I need to run partition addition once.

Comment: Right. So either do this in an operator whose parallelism is set to one, or check that `getRuntimeContext().getIndexOfThisSubtask() == 0`.

Comment: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/table/connectors/filesystem.html#partition-commit-policy is there a way to use this?

Comment: That does look interesting.